# How to return text value from .then in Cypress using JS or TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, cypress, return-value

I need to access data outside from then.

```
   function getText() {
    cy.get('#locator')
        .then(function($elem) {
            let aaa = cy.log($elem.text());
            return aaa.toString();
        });
   }

   var returnedValue = getText();
   cy.log(returnedValue);
```

I get the error: **Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'**, when I try to print the output in the Cypress test runner log.
[image]

Comment: Try returning `cy.get`?
(I'm aware that `cy` calls are not "true" promises, so my initial thought of "you can't do that" may be wrong.)

Comment: This was already asked just yesterday [Return text from function cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73926331/return-text-from-function-cypress)

Comment: And here [Return a value from a function in cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772883/return-a-value-from-a-function-in-cypress)

Comment: And here [How to return result from Cypress function after set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72492152/how-to-return-result-from-cypress-function-after-set)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return result from Cypress function after set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72492152/how-to-return-result-from-cypress-function-after-set)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `getText()` does not return anything, hence the `argument of type void...` error.
2. You're trying to convert a `cy.log()` command into a string, which is not feasible.

Instead, let's yield the result of your `getText()` command into a `.then()` that uses `cy.log()`;

```js
const getText = () => {
  return cy // return the entire chain
    .get('#locator')
    .then(($elem) => {
       return $elem.text(); // return the text of the element
    });
}

getText().then((result) => {
  cy.log(result);
});
```

If you need to do something besides `cy.log()` that value, just do the same, and use that `result` variable.

```js
getText().then((result) => {
  // code that uses result
});
```

I would not advise declaring a variable and setting it equal to `getText()`, because that is going to assign the variable a value of type `Chainable<string>`, and not `string`, which is not what you want or need.